# Microsoft LUIS: unable to set time zone (datetimeReference) for datetimeV2 entities

Tags: python, azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am using the V3 API to get predictions from a LUIS endpoint and I need a way to tell LUIS my time zone, so that relative time expressions (e.g. "in the past two hours", "in 10 minutes") are resolved properly by the datetimeV2 entity.

Everything works perfectly if I use the V2 API with the timezoneOffset option, but I am unable to make the V3 API work with the new option datetimeReference (which is supposed to replace timezoneOffset). Actually, I could not even figure out which value I should set for datetimeReference (an integer number? A datetime?).

Here are my attempts with Python. Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests

appId           = # my app id
subscriptionKey = # my subscription key

query = "tra 10 minuti" # = "in 10 minutes" (my app speaks Italian)

# ATTEMPT 1
# based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-data-alteration?tabs=V2#change-time-zone-of-prebuilt-datetimev2-entity,
# assuming it works the same way as timezoneOffset
endpoint = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/prediction/v3.0/apps/{appId}/slots/staging/predict?datetimeReference=120&subscription-key={subscriptionKey}&query={query}'
endpoint = endpoint.format(appId = appId, subscriptionKey = subscriptionKey, query = query)

response = requests.get(endpoint)

# ATTEMPT 2
# according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-api-v3
endpoint = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/prediction/v3.0/apps/{appId}/slots/staging/predict?'
endpoint = endpoint.format(appId = appId)

json = {
    "query" : query,
    "options":{
        "datetimeReference": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), # e.g. "2020-05-07T13:54:33". Not clear if that's what it wants
        "preferExternalEntities": True
    },
    "externalEntities":[],
    "dynamicLists":[]
}

response = requests.post(endpoint, json, headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey})
```

---

UPDATE: the correct way of sending the request in ATTEMPT 2 is

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, json = json, headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey})
```

Comment: You already linked to a document that explains that `datetimeReference` is supposed to be in ISO 8601 format and is supposed to go in the body of the request, like you've done in attempt 2. What exactly is unclear about the document? If there's something wrong with the document then you should consider posting that as feedback on the page itself. But since you've already posted a question here, can you explain what you expect to happen versus what is actually happening?

Comment: The document does not explicitly say what datetimeReference is (I have already sent a feedback), although I assume it is the datetime we want LUIS to consider as "now" when resolving relative time expressions. E.g.: if now it's 2020-05-08T10:08:23 in my time zone, I assumed that passing that as datetimeReference together with the query "in 10 minutes" would return an entity datetimeV2 resolved as 2020-05-08 10:18:23. But this is not what happens; instead, LUIS returns 2020-05-08 08:18:23, as if it thinks I am located in UTC+0 (it seems to ignore my datetimeReference option completely)

Comment: I just pasted the JSON from your question into Postman and filled in the properties with "in 10 minutes" and "2020-05-08T10:08:23". The returned entity says "2020-05-08T10:18:23" just like you expected. Can you try the request in Postman to verify? Can you think of anything you might be doing differently? You haven't shown the code for how you're handling the response, so could the problem be that you're converting the string from the returned entity into some kind of date-time object?

Comment: After also trying the request in Postman and seeing it work, I revised my Python request and found out I was just passing the json in the wrong argument (data instead of json). It now works perfectly, which also confirms my interpretation of the datetimeReference argument. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: That's very strange. I wonder how LUIS was able to read your query if it wasn't able to see the body of your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, your JSON should go in the `json` argument and not the `data` argument:

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, json = json, headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey})
```